# Critique my first C++ "Hello World" program

Tags: c++

This is my first attempt to write a simple C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Book {
    public:
    char title[30];

    Book(char *tit)  {
        strcpy(title,tit);
    };

    char *gettitle() {
        return title;
    }
};


int main() {

    Book miolibro((char *)"aaa");
    cout << miolibro.gettitle() << endl;

   std::vector<Book> vettorelibri; 
   for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        Book l( (char *)"aaa" );   // i tried something like "aaa"+i but it does not work

        vettorelibri.push_back(l);   
    }

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        cout << vettorelibri[i].gettitle() << endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 13):

It has been commented that when working in C++ you should use `std::string`.  Assuming you want to stay with C style strings (or at least understand how you ought to work with them, in case you ever have to), I have the following suggestions:

```
strcpy(title,tit);
```

`tit` can be larger than the buffer `title` allows.[1]  In that case, your program will crash or worse, continue running while corrupting some other part of memory.  To avoid that you should always use functions which let you track the size of the destination buffer and detect overflow.  For example:

```
strncpy(title, sizeof(title)-1, tit);
title[sizeof(title) - 1] = 0;
```

This has some undesirable traits in that it will silently truncate the string if the input is larger than the destination.  If you are working on a system that has the non-standard `strlcpy`, that has some cleaner error conditions:

```
if (strlcpy(title, sizeof(title), tit) >= sizeof(title)))
{
    // TODO: decide how to handle the error (in your case maybe throw
    // an exception)
}
```

Moving along the spectrum (from code that crashes given large input, to code that truncates the input, to code that errors out when the buffer in insufficient...), you might also want to dynamically allocate memory for this.

```
char *title;

Book(const char *tit)
{
   title = strdup(tit);
   if (!title) { throw std::bad_alloc(); }
}
```

This creates complications if a `Book` object is ever copied, so you need to handle that:

```
Book(const Book &b)
{
   title = strdup(b.title);
   if (!title) { throw std::bad_alloc(); }
}
```

And it needs to be freed when your object is destroyed:

```
~Book()
{
   free(title);
}
```

If this seems too complicated it's because for higher-level C++ code it probably is.  `std::string` will take care of all of this for you.  Note though that the memory layout of your object will be substantially different with these dynamic-memory approaches.[2]

Next up...

```
Book miolibro((char *)"aaa");
```

As a general rule, having to do casts like this is often an indicator that you're doing something wrong.  :-)  When writing code and reviewing the work of others' I tend to try to avoid as many unnecessary casts as possible.  A lot of times these mask bugs, for example casting a function to an incorrect function pointer type can produce crashes, or casting away `const` may crash when someone tries to modify a read-only buffer.  For reasons like this it's a good habit to watch for inappropriate casts when reading code, and be sure not to introduce them yourself; code like this should **offend** your sensibilities.  :-)  [3]

In your case, the issue is that string literals have the type `const char*`, so the compiler complains that you are passing this to something that doesn't have `const`.  So what you need to do here is:

```
Book(const char *tit)
{
    // ...
}
```

Footnotes and tangential comments:
[1] If there are any English speaking people who might read your code, I suggest you come up with a better name than `tit` for that variable.
[2] In the earlier example, characters of `title` exists alongside any other members of the class.  When using dynamic memory, there's now an extra pointer dereference going on to get to the characters.  In most cases this won't make a difference but you can think of theoretical cases where the former is desired over the latter.
[3] Side note: In my experience one way to tell that someone doesn't know what they're doing in C/C++ is the use of casts.  A sloppy programmer will write code that the compiler rejects, and then to get it "working" quickly they'll introduce casts to silence compiler warnings instead of fixing the actual problem.  If you are working on a team where people do this, I find it's sometimes a good indication to be skeptical of that person's work for other reasons.

Comment: thank you very much for comments!
yes, the string stuffs seems to be like too-lowlevel for me (i've never used c before but i have to deal with it), and for now i think i'll use std even if is a good thing know c-style string handling, thanks very much for the examples and collateral problem explanation!
then, ok, i'll try to train my sensibility on bad use of cast, thanks for this life advice ahah : )

Comment: Please note that strdup() is not standard C/C++ and may not work on C/C++ compilers. I would not advise beginners to use non-standard functions like this one.

Comment: You might want to clarify that the advice on `strlcpy` with termination using `sizeof` and on `strdup` an dynamic allocation are not possible to follow at the same time.

Answer (score 8):

I know I'm a little late, but let's take a look.

```
using namespace std;
```

There's no need for this.  Really.  You're already qualifying most of your names -- keep doing that.

```
class Book {
  public:
    char title[30];

    Book(char *tit)  {
        strcpy(title,tit);
    };

    char *gettitle() {
        return title;
    }
};
```

As others have said, use `std::string`.  As others have not said: **definitely** use `std::string`.  You cannot sanely mix raw C strings and exceptions without smart pointers.  In fact, mixing any dynamic allocation with exceptions without smart pointers is a great way to drive yourself insane, but in this case it's not even remotely justified as there's a class that does exactly what you want.

Now, let's see how `Book` can be rewritten:

```
class Book {
    std::string title;

  public:
    Book(std::string const& t) : title(t)
    {}

    std::string get_title() const {
        return title;
    }
};
```

Notice the funny syntax in the constructor.  That's called a constructor-initializer, and it's a good idea to initialise your objects that way when possible -- it might be faster, and it makes it more explicit.

Notice that the string is passed by const reference.  This means you don't copy it, but that you also can't change it -- you don't want to change it, so that's okay.  It has another benefit, but I'll show that later.

Finally, we make `get_title` const so that you can call it on a const instance of `Book`.  Not very important in your minimal code, but it pays off to be as [const-correct](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html) as possible.

```
int main() {
    Book my_book("aaa");
    std::cout << my_book.get_title() << '\n';
```

Yay, you know about how to initialise objects that don't have a default constructor.  That's a handy thing to know, and less common than I'd like to see it.  Notice that we don't need the cast any more -- in fact, we don't even need to explicitly call `std::string`s constructor.  That's because `std::string` can be constructed from a `char const*`, which `"aaa"` converts to.  (If you're curious, `"aaa"` *isn't* itself `char const*` -- it's `char const[4]`.)

You used `std::endl` here, but there's no need for that.  You can just output a newline character, and it'll get printed eventually -- `std::endl` makes sure it gets printed immediately, but unless the program crashes, it'll be outputted equally soon without it as far as the user can tell.

```
  std::vector<Book> vector_of_books; 
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
      vector_of_books.push_back(Book("aaa"));
```

Here's code that does exactly what you were doing, but with `Book`'s new constructor and with no temporary.  I think this is just as clear, but some may disagree.  An even clearer way to do this is

```
  std::vector<Book> vector_of_books(10, Book("aaa"));
```

That'll do the same thing, and describes the intent more clearly.

As an aside: you say that `"aaa"+i` didn't work.  That is indeed something that won't work, partly because C++ doesn't provide an all-that-easy way of joining a string together with something else.  Your best bet would be `"aaa" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i)`, unless you wanted to go through the trouble of explicitly creating a `stringstream`.  There are also functions like `atoi` and `snprintf`, but those are generally less safe or harder to use.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << vector_of_books[i].get_title() << '\n';
    }
};
```

This code is perfectly fine to use -- I applied some cosmetic changes, but they don't particularly matter.  Gabriel is suggesting you use iterators, but I don't think those make things any better:

```
    for (std::vector<Book>::iterator it = vector_of_books.begin();
         it < vector_of_books.end();
         ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << '\n';
    }
```

The code is much longer and the bonus in efficiency isn't going to matter.  Granted, with C++11 you could change the `std::vector<Book>::iterator` into `auto`, and then it would be decent, but in C++11 you could also just do:

```
    for (std::string const& book : vector_of_books)
        std::cout << book << '\n';
```

If this looks confusing, don't worry about it; it's most important that you get the basics down (like using `std::string`), and iterating is just a nice option that you can keep in mind for when it's more efficient/clearer.

Comment: Great answer!! BTW, you wrote `Bool` in one place where you meant `Book`.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using C++ instead of C, you should use `std::string` instead of `char` arrays.  Include `<string>`.

Answer (score 5):

There are several issues:

- If you use getter method for the title in `Book`, you probably want to hide the title field, so make it private
- If the title length constraint for 30 is arbitrary, you might want to change the title field to a pointer to string (learn more about what kind of strings you really want here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string)
- If you want to use the `Book` constructor with string literals (e.g. `"aaa"`), you should add const to the parameter type
- In the `Book` constructor `strcpy` is dangerous, because it doesn't check lengths of the strings (buffer overflow possible), you should better use [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/narrow/strncpy), or if you decide to use constants, you don't have to copy at all
- It is preferable to use camelcase or underscores for separating words in identifiers for readability, so rename the `gettitle` to `getTitle` or `get_title`, same holds for `miolibro` and `vettorilibri`.
- If you want to avoid casting string literals, use constants instead
- If you want to pass an object of a type you defined to an output stream (e.g. cout in your case), it is preferable to overload the `operator<<`.
- If you use a namespace (using keyword), you don't have to type the whole names unless a name clash is possible, in your case you can just write `vector` instead of `std::vector`.
- The proper way of constructing a new object is to call a constructor using the new operator, so you should replace the `Book l(...)`, which is implicit conversion AFAIK, with `new Book(...)`. Than should `vettorelibri.push_back(new Book("aaa" + i));` work as expected, given you switch to constants (`const char*` instead `of char*`).
- The preferred way of iterating over a `vector` is using an iterator instead of explicit indexing. You can read about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409348/iteration-over-vector-in-c

There might be some more problems, but this should be enough for a start:).

Comment: thanks! camelcase and namespacing are good style advices. then, thanks for string reference link and also iterator is a good things i have to learn!

Comment: Why he should use new operator to build an object? Is complete "legal" to build objects without the new operator. Why waste resources dynamic allocating an object when this is not needed.

Comment: `push_back(new Book(/*...*/))` leaks memory when `push_back` throws.  Also, there is no reason not to construct a `Book` on the stack.

Comment: I think the problem here is that he doesn't know how to create a Book object, I find new to be more general, but you are right, he could just as well use stack or malloc.

Comment: In addition to making the constructor's char* parameter const, the member function gettitle() should be declared as a constant member function: `char *gettitle() const`. The const keyword at the end simply means that this function won't modify any member variables inside the class. This is part of the concept called "const-correctness", leading to better programs.

Comment: -1; `new` is certainly the wrong way to go here, and you're advising the wrong way to handle the using-directive.